# Why is "Duplicate zip entry [classes.jar:android/support/v7/appcompat/R$styleable.class]" with android-sdk-plugin?

Tags: android, scala, sbt

I am using [pfn/android-sdk-plugin](https://github.com/pfn/android-sdk-plugin) in a project with the following `build.sbt`:

```
import android.Keys._

android.Plugin.androidBuild

platformTarget in Android := "android-19"

name := "LDApp"

organization := "com.myapps.app.android.ldapp"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

useProguard in Android := true

libraryDependencies ++= Seq (
  "com.myapps.libraries.android" %% "androidlibs" % "0.1-SNAPSHOT"
)

proguardCache in Android ++= Seq (
  ProguardCache("androidlibs") % "com.myapps.libraries.android" %% "androidlibs",
  ProguardCache("appcompat-v7") % "com.android.support" % "appcompat-v7"
)
```

Whenever I try to `sbt android:run`, I am getting error as `Duplicate entry`, appcompact-v7 is been included `myapps.libraries.android`, that is why I have not included explicitly in this application. Following is the error log

```
Copying resources from program jar [/Users/android/tmp/tmp/projects/LDApp/bin/classes.jar] (filtered)
java.io.IOException: Can't write [/Users/android/tmp/tmp/projects/LDApp/bin/classes.proguard.jar] (Can't read [/Users/android/tmp/tmp/projects/LDApp/bin/classes.jar(;;;;;;!META-INF/**,!rootdoc.txt)] (Duplicate zip entry [classes.jar:android/support/v7/appcompat/R$styleable.class]))
    at proguard.OutputWriter.writeOutput(OutputWriter.java:264)
    at proguard.OutputWriter.execute(OutputWriter.java:160)
    at proguard.ProGuard.writeOutput(ProGuard.java:372)
    at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:153)
    at android.Tasks$$anonfun$77.apply(tasks.scala:1197)
    at android.Tasks$$anonfun$77.apply(tasks.scala:1171)
    at scala.Function10$$anonfun$tupled$1.apply(Function10.scala:35)
    at scala.Function10$$anonfun$tupled$1.apply(Function10.scala:34)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
    at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:42)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:64)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
    at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:244)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:160)
    at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:30)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Can't read [/Users/android/tmp/tmp/projects/LDApp/bin/classes.jar(;;;;;;!META-INF/**,!rootdoc.txt)] (Duplicate zip entry [classes.jar:android/support/v7/appcompat/R$styleable.class])
    at proguard.InputReader.readInput(InputReader.java:232)
    at proguard.InputReader.readInput(InputReader.java:202)
    at proguard.OutputWriter.writeOutput(OutputWriter.java:253)
    at proguard.OutputWriter.execute(OutputWriter.java:160)
    at proguard.ProGuard.writeOutput(ProGuard.java:372)
    at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:153)
    at android.Tasks$$anonfun$77.apply(tasks.scala:1197)
    at android.Tasks$$anonfun$77.apply(tasks.scala:1171)
    at scala.Function10$$anonfun$tupled$1.apply(Function10.scala:35)
    at scala.Function10$$anonfun$tupled$1.apply(Function10.scala:34)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
    at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:42)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:64)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
    at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:244)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:160)
    at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:30)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Duplicate zip entry [classes.jar:android/support/v7/appcompat/R$styleable.class]
    at proguard.io.JarWriter.getOutputStream(JarWriter.java:139)
    at proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryWriter.getOutputStream(FilteredDataEntryWriter.java:105)
    at proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryWriter.getOutputStream(FilteredDataEntryWriter.java:105)
    at proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryWriter.getOutputStream(FilteredDataEntryWriter.java:92)
    at proguard.io.ClassRewriter.read(ClassRewriter.java:68)
    at proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryReader.read(FilteredDataEntryReader.java:87)
    at proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryReader.read(FilteredDataEntryReader.java:87)
    at proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryReader.read(FilteredDataEntryReader.java:87)
    at proguard.io.JarReader.read(JarReader.java:65)
    at proguard.io.DirectoryPump.readFiles(DirectoryPump.java:65)
    at proguard.io.DirectoryPump.pumpDataEntries(DirectoryPump.java:53)
    at proguard.InputReader.readInput(InputReader.java:228)
    at proguard.InputReader.readInput(InputReader.java:202)
    at proguard.OutputWriter.writeOutput(OutputWriter.java:253)
    at proguard.OutputWriter.execute(OutputWriter.java:160)
    at proguard.ProGuard.writeOutput(ProGuard.java:372)
    at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:153)
    at android.Tasks$$anonfun$77.apply(tasks.scala:1197)
    at android.Tasks$$anonfun$77.apply(tasks.scala:1171)
    at scala.Function10$$anonfun$tupled$1.apply(Function10.scala:35)
    at scala.Function10$$anonfun$tupled$1.apply(Function10.scala:34)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
    at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:42)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:64)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
    at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:244)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:160)
    at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:30)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
[error] (android:proguard) java.io.IOException: Can't write [/Users/android/tmp/tmp/projects/LDApp/bin/classes.proguard.jar] (Can't read [/Users/android/tmp/tmp/projects/LDApp/bin/classes.jar(;;;;;;!META-INF/**,!rootdoc.txt)] (Duplicate zip entry [classes.jar:android/support/v7/appcompat/R$styleable.class]))
[error] Total time: 34 s, completed 5 Sep, 2014 6:15:10 PM
```

`R$styleable.class` is been generated as part of application also and is part of compact-v7 library as well, how to resolve this issue, even though similar issues seen around those solutions have not helped.

Comment: Anybody any clue or any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got solution from [google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-on-android/wsl21a5ab-g) of "scala-on-android". Author of [pfn/android-sdk-plugin](https://github.com/pfn/android-sdk-plugin) provided the solution. Here is the solution

Since `androidlibs` is library project, it's `build.sbt` MUST have `libraryProject in Android := true`, this enables plugin not to include resource(`R.java & TR.scala`) files of libraries. If "compact" library resources are been referred by app then library has to be included in "libraryDependencies" of app explicitly. `typedResources in Android := false` has to be included in local library in case if your library shouldn't generate resource files